# OAuth2 access token limit in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign RestAPI Guide says "Up to 10 access_tokens are supported per userId."

I have been using demo.docusign.net account to create access tokens. More than 10 access tokens are generated by this account using the same Integrator key and username.

There are some  posts related to OAuth access token limit
DocuSign OAuth Token error - “An entry with the same key already exists” when access token limit crosses 10.

I verified lists of tokens generated at  Preferences -> connected Apps in my DocuSign web console. They are already been crossed 50 and no maximum limit exception been thrown by DocuSign endpoint.

So What is OAuth2 access token limit? Is it only applicable to Production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user OAuth token limit has been increased in the DocuSign Demo (Developer) environment to 200.  The OAuth token limit in production, though, is still the expected 10.  Once you try to create more than 10 tokens in production it will error out.

Comment: Quick Response is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer in that case?  Thx, -Ergin